# E2285 No match found for 'TScrCustomMemo :: FindTextInMemo (UnicodeString, TFindOptionEx)' in C++ Builder 10.3

Tags: c++builder, vcl, tms

I am using a TAdvMemo/TScrMemo in a form in C++ Builer 10.3. I am simply tring to implement the search/findtext method of the TAdvMemo/TScrMemo. But, I am getting the following error :

> [bcc32 error] Unit2.cpp (159): E2285 No match found for `'TScrCustomMemo :: FindTextInMemo (UnicodeString, TFindOptionEx)'`

I have a TAdvMemo/TScrMemo (Scripter), TButton, TEdit (for search)

```
void __fastcall TForm2::BtnSearchClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    String FSearch = EdtSearch->Text;
    Scripter->FindTextInMemo(FSearch,frDown);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Function signatures:

```
int __fastcall FindTextInMemo(System::UnicodeString SearchStr, Vcl::Dialogs::TFindOptions Options)/* overload */;
int __fastcall FindTextInMemo(System::UnicodeString SearchStr, TFindOptionsEx Options)/* overload */;
```

**ANSWER:**
Got it compile without error with the following code:

```
void __fastcall TForm2::BtnSearchClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    String FSearch = EdtSearch->Text;
    TFindOptions fn;
    fn = TFindOptions() << frDown;
    Scripter->FindTextInMemo(FSearch,fn);
}
```

Looks like the `frDown` component is from a Delphi set and I have to do like above to use it in C++.

Comment: I don't have TMS installed. What does the actual signature of `FindTextInMemo()` look like? Maybe there are more/different parameters present that you are not passing in?

Comment: These are the two signatures available in the ScrMemo.hpp file:

Comment: int __fastcall FindTextInMemo(System::UnicodeString SearchStr, Vcl::Dialogs::TFindOptions Options)/* overload */;
int __fastcall FindTextInMemo(System::UnicodeString SearchStr, TFindOptionsEx Options)/* overload */;

Comment: You should have posted your update as an answer instead. But yes, that is the correct solution. Though, you don't need the local variables: `Scripter->FindTextInMemo(EdtSearch->Text, TFindOptions() << frDown);`